# Whitelisting email domains in firebase

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I am currently creating a iOS application that is targeted towards university students. For security purposes, the only method of registration is by using their university emails (with the respected email domains). However for that to happen, I need to white list specific domains so emails like xxx@gmail.com can not register/login.

Now there are two ways to do this, first I need to create an if statement when the user is registering/logging in by checking if the email text field contains the appropriate email domain (that is in the white-list) and the second thing I need to do is set firebase rules for reading and writing if the auth user has and email domain that ends with the specified white-listed domain.

So far I was able to do this for one email domain but if I am targeting 100 schools, I cant have 100 if statements in my code (well I can but it would be very inefficient). So I was hoping there would be a way to include a csv file in my Xcode project for it to read from as well as having a cvs file that the firebase rules can read from. If that is not the case. I was hoping I can create an internal list of the email domains.

Comment: Another (more flexible overall) way would be to utilize a central server (could be as simple as hosting the 'csv' file on a server somewhere) to do a quick AJAX call and see if the domain was in an accepted list.  Using the 'server' gives you control over the file - who knows, tomorrow you might like gmail.com again :)  Most likely your app will need a server for various data anyway, so why not utilize it for domain verification up front?

Answer (score 1):

Since the domains you want to whitelist are likely to change over time, I suggest you keep track of them outside of the app itself. If you're using Cloud Firestore, for example, you could keep a collection of domains that are whitelisted.

```
domains:
    college.edu: {
       someinfo: true,
       // and so on
    },
    school.net: {
       someinfo: false,
       // etc
    }
```

Then, when a user wants to sign up, instead of calling `createUser` from the client, pass the information in the body of a request to a server endpoint. This would be a good use case for [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?authuser=0). Cloud Functions are available in Node.js, not Swift, so my example is written in JS.

```
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const domain = data.domain; // or you could regex the domain from the email. I just didn't feel like doing that here
  const email = data.email;
  const password = data.password;
  const domainRef = db.collection('domains').doc(domain);
  return domainRef.get()
    .then(doc => {
      if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log('No such document!');
      } else {
        console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
        admin.auth().createUser({
          email: email,
          password: password,
        })
        .then(function(userRecord) {
          // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
          console.log('Successfully created new user:', userRecord.uid);
          return {
            success: true
          };
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
          return {
            error: error
          };
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error getting document', err);
      return {
        error: error
      };
    });
  });
```

In this example, I use the [Firebase Admin Auth SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users?authuser=0) to create a new user.

Comment: I can also make some suggestions for securing data per user and per school if you're going for the above approach.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed proposal!! But I am not sure if this tackles both the database rules authentication and the check of the emailtextfield.text to see if it contains the white listed domain. I thought from the app side (with the text field) I would creat a struct that has the white listed domains and I would do a emailtextfield.contains() to see if the domain is in the struct. My biggest challenge is in the firebase authentication for writing and reading, I am not sure if there is a way to create a struct, I can’t find anything online that might help.

Comment: @OmarSaid you probably want to look into custom claims token, assign a different token based on different school/domain, and check the token in your rules.